# Problem with ellipse (rotated): incorrect position of any point is detected

Tags: c++, sdl-2

When the ellipse is not rotated with this formula [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmZtv.png). If value = 1 - point on the ellipse, if value > 1 - outside, if value < 1 - inside. The program works correctly.
Code:

```
int checkPointNoAngle(int x0, int y0, int x, int y, int a, int b)
{
    int value = (pow((x - x0), 2) / pow(a, 2)) + (pow((y - y0), 2) / pow(b, 2));
    return value;
}
```

I need to work with a rotated ellipse, so I used formula [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdcAV.png).
Now the program incorrectly determines the position of the point.

```
int checkPoint(int x0, int y0, int x, int y, int a, int b)
{
    int angle = 90;
    int value = (pow(cos(angle * M_PI / 180)*((x - x0)+sin(angle * M_PI / 180)*(y-y0)), 2) / pow(a, 2)) + (pow(sin(angle * M_PI / 180) * ((x - x0) - cos(angle * M_PI / 180) * (y - y0)), 2) / pow(b, 2));
    return value;
}
```

I drawing an ellipse using this code:

```
for (int t = 0; t < 360; t++)
{
    int x = a * cos(t);
    int y = b * sin(t);
    int x1 = x * cos(angle * M_PI / 180) + y * sin(angle * M_PI / 180);
    int y1 = -x * sin(angle * M_PI / 180) + y * cos(angle * M_PI / 180);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(ren, x1 + centerX, y1 + centerY);
}
```

The program draws the ellipse correctly, but determines the position of the point incorrectly.
Examples of work:
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a21L.png),[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2gOL.png),[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUaAT.png),[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRM45.png).
Example 4 and 5 works correctly with the checkPointNoAngle method.
I need to rotate the ellipse, so I created checkPoint method.
Example 6 indicates a bug.

Comment: What do you mean by *determines the position of the point incorrectly* ? Note also that `x = a * cos(t)* is suspicious, as `t` is not in radians. In addition, do you take into account floating point calculation inaccuracy and float-to-int truncation?

Comment: @Damien, added screenshots of the program. Screenshot [6] Indicates incorrect rendering with the checkPoint method.

Comment: It would be nice to have a minimum working code. For example, in the drawing code, what are the values of `centerX, centerY, angle`?

Comment: @Damien, added full code of project. centerX = 320 , centerY = 240, angle = 120;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was confusing a little bit. I tried to simplify the code corresponding to rotation and inverse rotation. The following code seems to work.

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <vector>
#include    <cmath>

struct Pt {int x, y;};

double checkPoint(int x0, int y0, int x, int y, int a, int b, int angle) {
    double ang = (angle * M_PI)/180;
    x = x - x0;
    y = y - y0;
    double xp = cos(ang)*x + sin(ang)*y;
    double yp = -sin(ang)*x + cos(ang)*y;
    double value = (xp*xp) / (a*a) + (yp*yp) / (b*b);
    return value;
}

std::vector<Pt> gene_ellipse (int centerX, int centerY, int angle, int a, int b) {
    std::vector<Pt> v;
    double c = cos (angle * M_PI/180);
    double s = sin (angle * M_PI/180);
    for (int t = 0; t < 360; t++) {
        double tt = M_PI * t / 180.0;
        double x = a * cos(tt);
        double y = b * sin(tt);
        int x1 = x * c - y * s;
        int y1 = x * s + y * c;
        v.push_back (Pt{x1 + centerX, y1 + centerY});
    }
    return v;
}

int main () {
    int centerX = 320;
    int centerY = 240;
    int angle = 120;        // in degrees
    int a = 200;
    int b = 100;

    int index = 25;

    auto v = gene_ellipse (centerX, centerY, angle, a, b);
    double check = checkPoint (centerX, centerY, v[index].x, v[index].y, a, b, angle);
    std::cout << "check = " << check << "\n";
}
```